# Select statement for overlapping dates

Tags: sql

I need a SELECT query that returns the RoomID's of rows in which the dates overlap each other, ex.
Client ID 10 and 6 arrive on different days, but they are assigned to the same room during their stay at the hotel.

```
RoomID ArrivalDate  DepartureDate ClientID
2      2020-11-02   2021-11-10    10
2      2021-11-01   2021-11-11    6
4      2021-10-18   2021-10-20    4
4      2021-12-13   2021-12-21    11
4      2021-12-14   2021-12-21    12
8      2021-12-10   2021-12-19    8
9      2021-09-20   2021-09-25    2
9      2021-09-21   2021-09-25    1
9      2021-12-10   2021-12-15    7
10     2021-10-19   2021-10-26    5
11     2021-10-02   2021-10-10    3
11     2021-12-12   2021-12-18    9
12     2021-10-04   2021-10-09    2
```

```
CREATE DATABASE Hotel;

CREATE TABLE reservations (
  roomID INT NOT NULL,
  ArrivalDate DATE NOT NULL,
  DepartureDate DATE NOT NULL,
  clientID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (roomID, ArrivalDate),
  CHECK (ArrivalDate <= DepartureDate)
);
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: That's the sample table data. Expected result would be RoomID's where the dates overlap eachother.

Comment: The result of `(S1,T1) OVERLAPS (S2,T2)` is the result of the following expression: 
`(S1 > S2 AND NOT (S1 >= T2 AND T1 >= T2)) OR (S2 > S1 AND NOT (S2 >= T1 AND T2 >= T1)) OR (S1 = S2 AND (T1 <> T2 OR T1 = T2))`. I.e. the accepted answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get overlaps using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.RoomID = t.RoomId and
                    t2.ClientID <> t.ClientId and
                    t2.ArrivalDate < t.DepartureDate and
                    t2.DepartureDate > t.ArrivalDate
             );
```

Comment: Missing `and`, or is it `or`, between the last two conditions. BTW, will consider a t2 2020 date overlapping a t 2021 date.